# Why does pivot_longer convert column type from 'double' to 'list'

Tags: r, arrays, pivot

After my data frame is converted to long, manipulated, then converted back to wide, the column types seem to have changed.

```
x = data.frame(A = rnorm(100), 
               b = rnorm(100)) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())

typeof(x[,'A'])
# produces "double"

x3 = x %>% pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)

typeof(x3[,'A'])
# produces "list"

typeof(x3[,'A'] %>% unlist())
# produces "double"
```

This is a problem because I want to loop through an array and assign parts of the df to parts of the array. For example:

```
arr = array(dim = c(2,100))
# arr has type 'logical'

arr[,1] = x3[,'A']
# arr now has type 'list'

arr[,2] = x3[,'A']

#last line gives me: 'Error in arr[, 2] = x3[, "A"] : incorrect number of subscripts on matrix'
```

Assigning a slice of the array to a list seems to convert the whole thing to a list. I believe I can get round this by replacing the last line with `arr[,2] = x3[,'A'] %>% unlist()`, but it's suck strange behaviour I want to know what's going on.

Comment: Good question, I don't know the answer. Specially after having checked `typeof(x3[['A']])`. It's a tibble thing, try to pipe the pivot instruction to `as.data.frame()` and run the rest of your code, `x3[,'A']` is now a `"double"` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `x3` is a `tibble` and using `x3[, 'A']` is still a `tibble` which you could check via `class(x3[,'A'])`. And as a `tibble` or a `data.frame` is basically a `list` `typeof` will give you a type of `list` (check e.g. `typeof(mtcars)`). This is one of the differences between a `data.frame` and a `tibble`. In case of a `data.frame` `x3[,'A']` would be simplified to a vector by default which is not the case for a `tibble`.

If your want a vector then you have to be more explicit when slicing from a `tibble` by using `x3[,'A', drop = TRUE]` or `x3[["A"]]` or `x3$A`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(123)

x = data.frame(A = rnorm(100), 
               b = rnorm(100)) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number())

x3 <- x %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)

class(x3[,'A'])
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

typeof(x3$A)
#> [1] "double"

typeof(x3[,'A', drop = TRUE])
#> [1] "double"

typeof(x3[['A']])
#> [1] "double"
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't appreciate the differences between `data.frame` and `tibble`. Easiest solution for me was to convert x3 back to a data.frame: `x3 = x %>% pivot_longer(-id) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>% as.data.frame()`. Using `drop = TRUE` would also work but not as neat.